# Activiti modeler: Customized editor and service tasks with specific attributes

Tags: user-interface, jbpm, bpmn, activiti

I use [Activiti](http://www.activiti.org/) as BPMN 2.0 workflow manager. The Activiti modeler is a graphical user interface intended to use in the browser to model these processes.

I want to customize the editor interface in the following way:

- removal of unneeded bpmn elements so that the UI shows only the relevant task types
- disabling attributes for specific tasks so that the UI shows only the relevant ones
- addition of new tasks with predefined attributes

I read something about [Stencil Sets](http://forums.activiti.org/en/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=397&view=next), but I am not sure if that fits to my requirements. Also there is tutorial in the User Guide for something similar when using the Activiti Designer which runs in Eclipse and not in the Browser: [Extending Activiti Designer](http://www.activiti.org/userguide/index.html#N11AFE) (it is marked as experimental though)

Are Stencil Sets the way to go and do they fulfill my requirements? Any pointers to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this if you checkout Signavio Core Components (on which Activiti Modeler is based), modify the sources and rebuild the web app.

http://code.google.com/p/signavio-core-components/

Answer (score 1):

You can check the link below where you can get some clues to modify stencils and one of part of your work will be done.

[How to customize Activiti-Signavio modeler](http://forums.activiti.org/en/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=2715)

But still I am looking for generating bpmn2.0 xml which can be directly get executed to activity.
I will post again if able to produce it.

Comment: Appreciating your initiative. Hope we will find a proper solution.